# How can I insert missing rows of dates and fill in missing values for other columns based off of another column?

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R and I'm looking to take a sample data.table I have of credit repayment data for a user, and fill in dates between each of their logged payment dates so I can calculate the "estimated payment per day" in a new column.

I'm working with [this dataset](https://datahub.io/tfeuerbach/energy_repayment_data) but have created an updated "cumulative" table that includes the relevant data. The R code for how I obtained the "cumulative" data table is below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(summarytools)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dataset <- read.csv('anonymized_repmts.csv')

# Create column for repayment per day

dataset$repmt_per_day <- (dataset$repmt_amt / dataset$repmt_freq)

# Create column for cumulative amount

payments <- data.table(dataset, key = "uuid")
payments[, cumm_amt := cumsum(repmt_amt), uuid][]

# Cumulative payments dataset

cumulative <- payments[, .(uuid, repmt_date, repmt_amt, repmt_per_day, cumm_amt)]
```

To summarize, a user(ID:001) repays credit every month on the cumulative data table and I would like to add rows for each user, that show every day that falls between each original logged repayment while creating a new column "repmnt_per_day" that estimates the daily payment. I would like to have the missing values for the columns be filled if possible.

Thanks in advance for the help, I don't need any answers given but just some guidance towards a package or tool within I could use would be amazing!